# It's a bad idea to keep records with a 5000 characters text long in a mediumtext column?

Tags: mysql, performance

An user can open a question in a forum. He can post a text quite long. So I decided to store it in a `mediumtext` column.

Other users can answer to that question. They can post a text of maximum 5000 characters.

As both, the question and the answers are "posts" for me, I am storing them in the same column.

How bad is that if we think about performance or database size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**  Don't worry.

**Long answer:**

If you are willing to limit to 64KB, use `TEXT` instead of `MEDIUMTEXT`.  I don't think `VARCHAR(5000)` has any benefit over either of them in any version of MySQL.

Is the question about MEDIUMtext?  `MEDIUMTEXT` has a 3-byte length field for overhead; `TEXT` and `VARCHAR(256 to 65525)` has 2-byte.  The difference is insignificant if the column will typically have hundreds to thousands of characters.

I would simply make it `MEDIUMTEXT` and spit at the user only if the `INSERT` complains that it is truncated (at 16MB).  (Actually, there may be some other tunables that will cause trouble somewhere between 1MB and 16MB.  And note that that is "bytes", not "characters".)

The `ROW_FORMAT` and the actual size of the text combine to say whether the text is stored "on-record" or "off-record".  The difference should be a problem for the app you describe.  (Danblack's 768 is not the only factor in the algorithm.)

As danblack mentioned, there is an issue with performance in some queries.  But 5000 is already over the cutoff.  That is, any `SELECT` that needs a temp table will automatically do it on disk.

Answer (score 1):

`varchar` columns can handle 65535 characters. All `varchar`, `char`, `*text` and `blob` above after 768 bytes these are [stored off-row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html).

So you still can use `varchar` of a higher value, or `text` types however do you see fit.

At some point older MySQL versions couldn't sort in memory on a `text` column but I think that was fixed in 8.0.

Don't worry about the performance or database size on this, MySQL handles the internals to keep it doing the best it can.